# Serialization Delay Across Variable Speed Network

Tags: networking, udp, switch-statement, latency

I'm working with a network where there the inbound line is a fast, 1 gig line, which hits an edge switch and is then routed via a T1 to a separate internal 1 gig switch, with a 1 gig line output. Something like this:

[outside] (1 gig line) -> [edge device] (T1 line) -> [1 gig switch] (1 gig line) -> end

I'm working with mostly max frame packets, 1500 bytes -- I understand that the first serialization to the T1 line costs about 12 ms, but does this serialization delay occur once or twice? At the second switch, the 1 gig device, to serialize the packet onto the 1 gig line, does it cost on the order of 12ms again or is it done at the 1gig speed of only about 10ish us?

Answer (score 0):

When you have a link at T1 speed compared to GigabitEthernet, the overwhelming majority of serialization delay comes from serializing from GigabitEthernet onto T1.  Keep in mind that you also serialize from T1 to Gig on the other side, but the delay is so small it's not worth considering.

Also understand that you will exprience delay from the speed of light (or electricity) through the cabling.  When sending across the US, this adds up to usually 50ms or more... depending on the physical path that your traffic takes.

Finally be aware that slightly increased packet loss is normal when you go from GigabitEthernet speeds to T1... most routers simply cannot handle that kind of speed transition very gracefully without dropping more packets than "normal".  If you have the option of increasing your egress packet buffers on the T1 side (Cisco routers certainly have that option), it's is a good idea.  Your router vendor might have published guidelines for these kind of situations...